# removeClass() doesn't remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

removeClass doesn't remove the class `selected` from `div.upvote` in the js below, but addClass() works fine. Why is that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";

    $('div.upvote').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).parents('li.book').attr('id');
        var vote_type = 'up';

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var vote_action = 'recall-vote';
            $.post('/b/vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type, action: vote_action}, function (response) {
                if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                    $('li#' + id)
                        .find('div.upvote')
                        .removeClass('selected');
                    $('div.vote-tally span.num').html(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            var vote_action = 'vote';
            $.post('/b/vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type, action: vote_action}, function (response) {
                if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                    $('li#' + id)
                        .find('div.upvote')
                        .addClass('selected');
                    $('div.vote-tally span.num').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to .removeClass() in your code ...

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle to make real test over it?

Comment: Sorry, I had just tested toggleClass() and I pasted the new code without re-editing.

Comment: are you sure you are getting numeric response `if($.isNumeric(response))`'

Comment: @PraveenPrasad: yes, I'm sure.

Comment: replace this `var id = $(this).parents('li.book').attr('id');`  with var id = $(this).parents('li.book:first').attr('id');

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/NHEQX/

Comment: @PraveenPrasad: You were right, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $('div.upvote').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).parents('li.book').attr('id');
        var vote_type = 'up';


        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var vote_action = 'recall-vote';
            (function (response) { // skip ajax, just call success callback
                if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                    $('li#' + id)
                            .find('div.upvote')
                            .removeClass('selected');
                    $('div.vote-tally span.num').html(response);
                }
            }(123)); // fake numeric response
        } else {
            var vote_action = 'vote';
            (function (response) {
                if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                    $('li#' + id)
                            .find('div.upvote')
                            .addClass('selected');
                    $('div.vote-tally span.num').html(response);
                }
            }(123));
        }
    });
}) // ) missed
```

**HTML:**

```
<li id="li-id" class="book">
    <div class="upvote selected">upvote</div>
</li>​
```

With fake data all works fine. So you have a problem with non-numeric response or with missed **)**

Comment: I had a typo (if instead of elif) in my view that caused it to send a non-integer error-response.

Answer (score 0):

i remember toggle function has a bug in some browser. so you can user removeClass instead of toggle